# Convert Single Digit Month and Day to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime

Looking at time format specifiers I don't see any options for dates like `2/5/2010` (Month/Day/Year, single digit, no leading spaces). Are there any built in methods for converting dates in this format?

Comment: Downvote deserved, I was being pretty dense with this one....

Comment: not in my opinion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`as.POSIXct('2/5/2010',format='%m/%d/%Y')`

see `?strptime` for formatting options.

Comment: I was confusing myself by using the wrong year against my data. Since the documentation says %m should have leading zeros I mistakenly thought that was what was throwing my results off.

Comment: I upvoted the question because I do think that the documentation isn't clear on this subject and I think it should say "leading zeros or with a leading space for a single-digit number".

Answer (score 6):

In R, use

```
strptime('2/5/2010', "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The documentation of *strptime* is misleading.

%m and %d can deal with both single digit month R and dual dig