# Error in if (nchar(i) == 10) { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, date

I want to make a function that runs through a column of dates (data type is characters) and check whether or not it is 10 characters long. If it is, then I want to retain the characters and put it into an element for later use in my other functions. If it is not 10 characters long I would like to insert "0" at position 5 of the string. The characters are dates (e.g. "2016/7/23" and "2016/11/23"). If it is "2016/11/23" I want to keep this the same (this is 10 characters long). If it is "2016/7/23" (this is 9 characters long) I want to add a "0" at position 5 to make it "2016/07/23".

If it does, I want to put the character in "new", if it does not equal 10 characters then I want it to add a "0" into the string at position 5 of the string, then put it into "new". I am running into the problem [Error in if (nchar(i) == 10) { : the condition has length > 1] and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
for (i in cvdcounttwo_1c_fix){
  if (nchar(i) == 10) {new <- i}
  else{
  nxew <- sub("(.{5})(.*)", "\\10\\2", i)}}
```

Without the if statement this works, but this adds a 0 at position 5 of the string regardless of the string length.

`for (i in cvdcounttwo_1c_fix){ new <- sub("(.{5})(.*)", "\\10\\2", i)}`

Comment: Could you edit your question to make this reproducible (i.e., example data)? Some tips on how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There is no need to prefix, we can convert both strings: with leading zero and without leading zero, with the same format `%m`. Try this example: `as.Date(c("2016/11/23", "2016/7/23"), "%Y/%m/%d")`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/9119180/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be easier if you take advantage of R's `Date` format. I would convert the strings to `Date` format using `as.Date()`, specifying what notation is being used. This will add a leading zero to any of the months or days that have only one digit. Then you can use `format()` to convert the dates back to strings printed in any notation you want.

```
date_strings <- c("2016/7/23", "2016/11/23")

dates <- as.Date(date_strings, format = '%Y/%m/%d')
# [1] "2016-07-23" "2016-11-23"

format(dates, format = '%Y/%m/%d')
# [1] "2016/07/23" "2016/11/23"
```